# Open Data for the monthly or quarterly GDP of the Eurozone (or Europe 19)

Tags: data-request, europe

Trying to find a source that provides monthly or at worst quarterly data of the GDP in the Eurozone area. During my research, I found this link [click](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/tgm/table.do?tab=table&init=1&plugin=1&pcode=tec00001&language=en) but it is annual and it does not allow you to change to quarter.

Apart from that I would like it to be reliable and free of charge.

Any thoughts?

**Edit:**

So I have also found this [1](http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickview.do?SERIES_KEY=MNA.Q.Y.I8.W2.S1.S1.B.B1GQ._Z._Z._Z.EUR.V.N&periodSortOrder=ASC) which is quarterly data published by ECB. However there seems to be a large deviation on the values reported by these two links. Their difference is not that obvious to me.

Any insights on their differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDP isn't calculated monthly.

You can use the ECB numbers and cite to the ECB. The metadata page is useful.

ECB data is seasonally adjusted. The Eurostat data doesn't say seasonally adjusted that I could find.